# Resize div with drag handle when rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

*I could find similar questions involving jQuery UI lib, or only CSS with no handle to drag, but nothing with pure maths.*

What I try to perform is to have a resizable and rotatable div. So far so easy and I could do it.

But it gets more complicate when rotated, the resize handle does calculation in opposite way: it decreases the size instead of increasing when dragging away from shape.

Apart from the calculation, I would like to be able to change the cursor of the resize handle according to the rotation to always make sense. For that I was thinking to detect which quadrant is the resize handle in and apply a class to change cursor via CSS.

1. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I want to have a lightweight code and simple UI. So my requirement is jQuery but nothing else. I prefer not to add jQuery UI.
2. I could develop until achieving this but it's getting too mathematical for me now. I need to detect when the rotation is enough to have the calculation reversed.

I am also looking for UX improvements.

Here is my code and a Codepen to try: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrAWJA

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    html, body {height: 100%;}

    #square {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 20% auto;
        background: orange;
        position: relative;
    }
    .handle * {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: turquoise;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .resize {
        bottom: -10px;
        right: -10px;
        cursor: nwse-resize;
    }
    .rotate {
        top: -10px;
        right: -10px;
        cursor: alias;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            new resizeRotate('#square');
        });

        var resizeRotate = function(targetElement)
        {
            var self = this;
            self.target = $(targetElement);
            self.handles = $('<div class="handle"><div class="resize" data-position="bottom-right"></div><div class="rotate"></div></div>');
            self.currentRotation = 0;
            self.positions = ['bottom-right', 'bottom-left', 'top-left', 'top-right'];

            self.bindEvents = function()
            {
                self.handles
                    //=============================== Resize ==============================//
                    .on('mousedown', '.resize', function(e)
                    {
                        // Attach mouse move event only when first clicked.
                        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e)
                        {
                            var topLeft = self.target.offset(),
                                bottomRight = {x: topLeft.left + self.target.width(), y: topLeft.top + self.target.height()},
                                delta = {x: e.pageX - bottomRight.x, y: e.pageY - bottomRight.y};

                            self.target.css({width: '+=' + delta.x, height: '+=' + delta.y});
                        })
                        .one('mouseup', function(e)
                        {
                            // When releasing handle, round up width and height values :)
                            self.target.css({width: parseInt(self.target.width()), height: parseInt(self.target.height())});
                            $(document).off('mousemove');
                        });
                    })
                    //============================== Rotate ===============================//
                    .on('mousedown', '.rotate', function(e)
                    {
                        // Attach mouse move event only when first clicked.
                        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e)
                        {
                            var topLeft = self.target.offset(),
                                center = {x: topLeft.left + self.target.width() / 2, y: topLeft.top + self.target.height() / 2},
                                rad = Math.atan2(e.pageX - center.x, e.pageY - center.y),
                                deg = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 135;

                            self.currentRotation = deg;
                            // console.log(rad, deg);
                            self.target.css({transform: 'rotate(' + (deg)+ 'deg)'});
                        })
                        .one('mouseup', function(e)
                        {
                            $(document).off('mousemove');
                            // console.log(self.positions[parseInt(self.currentRotation/90-45)]);
                            $('.handle.resize').attr('data-position', self.positions[parseInt(self.currentRotation/90-45)]);
                        });
                    });
            };
            self.init = function()
            {
                self.bindEvents();
                self.target.append(self.handles.clone(true));
            }();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="all">
        <div id="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Transform the mouse position into the rectangle's local coordinate system (with its inverse transform) and you end up with the base case, which you already seem to handle well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But how do you detect when it has to be inverse or not, u have to detect if we are in a certain quadrant no?

Comment: Why do you have to detect? It will always be the inverse. And if it is not transformed (i.e. the transform is the identity matrix), then the inverse will be the identity matrix, too.

Comment: Thanks for support but I need more help on that, I edited my question and started a bounty. Can you help me edit my code or an example to show me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code that achieves what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  new resizeRotate('#square');
});

var resizeRotate = function(targetElement) {
  var self = this;
  self.target = $(targetElement);
  self.handles = $('<div class="handle"><div class="resize" data-position="bottom-right"></div><div class="rotate"></div></div>');
  self.currentRotation = 0;
  self.w = parseInt(self.target.width());
  self.h = parseInt(self.target.height());
  self.positions = ['bottom-right', 'bottom-left', 'top-left', 'top-right'];

  self.bindEvents = function() {
    self.handles
      //=============================== Resize ==============================//
      .on('mousedown', '.resize', function(e) {
        // Attach mouse move event only when first clicked.
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var topLeft = self.target.offset();           

            var centerX = topLeft.left + self.target.width() / 2;
            var centerY = topLeft.top + self.target.height() / 2;

            var mouseRelativeX = e.pageX - centerX;
            var mouseRelativeY = e.pageY - centerY;

            //reverse rotation
            var rad = self.currentRotation * Math.PI / 180;
            var s = Math.sin(rad);
            var c = Math.cos(rad);
            var mouseLocalX = c * mouseRelativeX + s * mouseRelativeY;
            var mouseLocalY = -s * mouseRelativeX + c * mouseRelativeY;

            self.w = 2 * mouseLocalX;
            self.h = 2 * mouseLocalY;
            self.target.css({
              width: self.w,
              height: self.h
            });
          })
          .one('mouseup', function(e) {
                $(document).off('mousemove');
          });
      })
      //============================== Rotate ===============================//
      .on('mousedown', '.rotate', function(e) {
        // Attach mouse move event only when first clicked.
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var topLeft = self.target.offset(),
              center = {
                x: topLeft.left + self.target.width() / 2,
                y: topLeft.top + self.target.height() / 2
              },
              rad = Math.atan2(e.pageX - center.x, center.y - e.pageY) - Math.atan(self.w / self.h),
              deg = rad * 180 / Math.PI;

            self.currentRotation = deg;
            self.target.css({
              transform: 'rotate(' + (deg) + 'deg)'
            });
          })
          .one('mouseup', function(e) {
            $(document).off('mousemove');
            $('.handle.resize').attr('data-position', self.positions[parseInt(self.currentRotation / 90 - 45)]);
          });
      });
  };
  self.init = function() {
    self.bindEvents();
    self.target.append(self.handles.clone(true));
  }();
}
```

The major changes are the following:

In the resize event, the mouse position is transformed to the local coordinate system based on the current rotation. The size is then determined by the position of the mouse in the local system.

The rotate event accounts for the aspect ratio of the box (the `- Math.atan(self.w / self.h)` part).

If you want to change the cursor based on the current rotation, check the angle of the handle (i.e. `self.currentRotation + Math.atan(self.w / self.h) * 180 / Math.PI`). E.g. if you have a cursor per quadrant, just check if this value is between 0..90, 90..180 and so on. You may want to check the documentation if and when negative numbers are returned by `atan2`.

Note: the occasional flickering is caused by the box not being vertically centered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is quite what I am looking for. Except that now I see the result with flickering, loss of handle if you play too much and not very user friendly after all I am a bit desappointed by my idea. Is there some UX improvement anyone can suggest me? :)

Comment: The flickering can probably be avoided if some care is taken. The code above was just to illustrate the transformation to local coordinates. What do you mean by loss of handle?

Comment: When you rotate then drag away sometimes the handle is lost then its like when you try to drag element out of browser. So I updated my codepen with your code and added min-width and min-height to prevent square to be unusable if you drag until 0. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLgVOZ. The flickering remains and i understand what you mean by the box is not vertical align but how could i do this if this tool is supposed to apply on wysiwyg images. I cannot vertical align them. Why does the flickering happen on bottom part whereas it did not in my first attempt?

Comment: It will probably help if you adjust the position to fix the center after scaling.

Comment: By fix center u mean absolute/relative positioning and calculation of top/left position as you drag?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Nico's answer is mostly correct, but the final result calculation is incorrect -> which is causing the flickering BTW.  What is happening is the increase or decrease in size is being doubled by the 2x multiplication.  The original half-width should be added to the new half-width to calculate the correct new width and height.

Instead of this:

```
self.w = 2 * mouseLocalX;
self.h = 2 * mouseLocalY;
```

It should be this:

```
self.w = (self.target.width() / 2) + mouseLocalX;
self.h = (self.target.height() / 2) + mouseLocalY;
```

Comment: Thank you @thomas I pasted Nico's answer in a codepen and edited it with your correction and it works great! Too bad I dropped the idea 2 years ago along with jQuery haha. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwREWe