# How to calculate the center of a rotated element, after resizing it

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, svg, geometry

I've already asked this [same question months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661059/rotate-a-resized-rectangle-with-svg-and-javascript), but no one was able to answer me, even after making a [fully functional example on Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/fXT0kZcRwJTPb7wQVHpg/), then, I am going to ask it again, and yes, I still have the same problem.

**My problem**: *find the centre of an element who have some rotation in it, after resizing it, to use it as the new pivot of rotation*.

In my practical example, it is possible to see the problem in action; I have created two circles to show the problem better. After rotating and resizing the element, it's possible to see how the red and blue circles are apart from each other.

**Blue Circle**: the "correct" position of the centre, achieved by setting the cx/cy coordinates as the calculated element centre, plus, applying the transform rotate in it. The transform translates the circle to the correct position.

**Red Circle**: same as the blue circle, minus the transform rotate, these values are the ones used as the rotation pivot for the transform rotate().

My assumptions until here: By applying the transform `rotate()` in the blue circle, I'm considering the rotation angle in the calculated centre, so all I have to do is replicate the matrix calculations made by the `rotate()` function. I'm already doing this with the four handles that the user can click to make a rotation, what could go wrong?

**My goal**: *Resize an element with rotation keeping the pivot of rotation in the centre*.

I think [this answer gave me some info](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/86784), the math here helped me with the rotation handles starting position, but still, I can't find the right way to calculate the new centre after the resize.

The example was made using D3js + AngularJS v1. I work actively with both, but I am new to the geometry math world.

Again, [this is the project on Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/fXT0kZcRwJTPb7wQVHpg/).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037565/resize-div-with-drag-handle-when-rotated/40263364#40263364) seems to do something similar.

Comment: What's wrong with simple `Center.X = (Corner[0].X + Corner[2].X) / 2` ?

Comment: You can calculate coordinate the centre of an element? I think you can.
Then transform this coordinate with your **some rotation in it, after resizing it, to use it as the new pivot of rotation** - You calculate New centre coordinate!!

Comment: It looks like you are keeping your own copy of the centre coordinates and updating them yourself iteratively as you go.  Why not just find the centre of the image at the start, then any time you need to find the current centre, just transform those (orginal) centre coords with the current transform?

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks for your suggestion, but the behaviour I want to achieve is a bit different, the can rotate from all corners, and element can be resized, what will change the centre, also, the user can apply rotate/translate transforms.

Comment: @MBo I tried that already, the new CX and CY I get doesn't account for rotation and translation by doing this, I've got the centre math right, the problem is after the rotation is applied, the coordinate system changes too

Comment: @Ivan.s Rotate around what? The original center?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I think this can work, but I can't quite get your point here, you want me to: store the original center point, when the user finishes resizing, apply the transforms (rotate, translate) over the stored value using matrix math?

Comment: Calculate centre of element in the beginning. This centre have coordinate, transform it (this coordinate as you transform another, NOT CENTRE COORDINATE) with transformation, thus  this is NEW CENTRE

Answer (score 3):

To get the centre of the transformed and rotated element, the most accurate way would probably be to get the browser to calculate it for you.

First create an SVGPoint object to hold our original centre point.

```
var centre = svg.createSVGPoint();
```

Initialize this point with the centre of the original object.  You can get that by calling `getBBox()` on the element, and performing a smiple calculation.

```
var bbox = obj.getBBox();
centre.x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
centre.y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
```

Next, get the transform matrix from the `transform` attribute of the transformed object

```
var  matrix = transformedObj.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix
```

Now we can transform our SVGPoint object with this matrix.

```
var transformedCentre = centre.matrixTransform(matrix);
```

After this, the `x` and `y` properties of `transformedCentre` should be your transformed centre point.

This should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Paul, in fact, your answer gave me more insight about the SVG matrix calculations, I was able to update my example with your changes, after using `scale` to resize the element the math seems to be right, but, I'm still struggling. Please take a look at my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ObOMImCsZgSAvaSaGwBB). It seems that something is missing.